# Referencing URLs for other views in Django 1.8 with no arguments

Tags: django, django-views

I am working on a simple Django 1.8 application with a template that referencesa url that points to another view. The views are all class-based generic views.

When attempting to load up the page, I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$add/$']

<form action="{% url 'movies:add' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

My app's url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.MovieList.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^add/$', views.MovieCreate.as_view(), name="add"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', views.MovieDelete.as_view(), name="delete"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', views.MovieUpdate.as_view(), name="update")
]
```

The template being used:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="?sort=title">Title</a></td>
        <td><a href="?sort=year">Year</a></td>
        <td><a href="?sort=director">Director</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% for movie in movie_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
        <td>{{movie.year}}</td>
        <td>{{movie.director}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<form action="{% url 'movies:add' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Add Movie" />
</form>
```

The two views in question:

```
class MovieList(ListView):
    model = Movie
    queryset = Movie.objects.order_by("title", "-year", "director")
    context_object_name = "movie_list"
    template_name = "movies/index.html"


class MovieCreate(CreateView):
    model = Movie
    fields = ["title", "year", "director"]
    template_name = "movies/add_movie.html"
```

This is strange to me since the correct URL is being resolved in the template and there are no variables expected by the `CreateView` (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$add/$']
```

This means that the regex used to include your app's urls ends with a `$`. It works for an empty pattern such as your `MovieList`, but not for non-empty patterns. Remove the `$` in that regex and it'll work.

Comment: I've done that, but the error appears with the new path, too. EDIT: Ah, it was the one in the `$` in the project's URL config.

Comment: Remove the `$` where you include these patterns, not in the `add/` pattern itself. The `$` indicates the end of the string, so the final `patterns tried` should look like `[u'add/$']`.